# Redis 2.8 Memory efficiency make test error

Tags: redis

I'm attempting to install Redis 2.8 but when I ran `make test`, it threw out an error for this:

> *** [err]: Memory efficiency with values in range 16384 in tests/unit/memefficiency.tcl Expected condition '$efficiency >=
>   $expected_min_efficiency' to be true (0.83004811885510699 >= 0.90)

What does this mean for the server that I'm installing this on? It used to work with Redis 2.6

Thanks!

Comment: According to antirez on the mailing list, it is a false positive. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/RIk2Ic5H9QY/hu3nq44APyEJ. This is the github issue https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1298

Comment: Thanks. Saw that as well. So it's safe to ignore?

Comment: Not sure.. I guess it would be prudent to use the previous version until 2.8 is used by the large scale users. The github issue is actively updated. No resolution yet.

Comment: Thanks @Pramod. 2.8.1 fixed this make test issue. Was a false positive. https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.8/00-RELEASENOTES